# Use of pronouns with mythical creatures

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

How should we refer to such figures from mythology and occultism like: [Lucifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer), [Fenrir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenrir), [Scylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scylla), [Astaroth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astaroth), [Beelzebub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub), [Baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet), [Minotaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur), [Golem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem), etc - **he**, **she** or **it**?

Famously, [the general rule](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/gendered-pronouns-use-animals-objects-people/) is to use `he/she` only with pets you have personal feelings to and `it` with all others. However, what about mythological creatures? They are neither humans nor animals in a full sense, just some living beings that posses both features of animated and non-animated things.

Excerpt from Wikipedia article about [Scylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scylla):

> Scylla made **her** first appearance in Homer's Odyssey, where Odysseus and his crew encounter **her** and Charybdis on their travels.

Excerpt from Wikipedia article about [Baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet):

> Lévi's Baphomet is the source of the later Tarot image of the Devil in the Rider-Waite design. The concept of a downward-pointing pentagram on **its** forehead was enlarged upon by Lévi in his discussion

For me these two creatures has no formal differences in regards to possession of animated features, even Scylla is lesser a human-like than Baphomet because she (it?) had no anthropomorphic features at all [[1]](https://sites.google.com/site/horrepicz/myths/charybdis-and-the-scylla)[[2]](https://godofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Scylla), simply a monster. Nevertheless she is used with **she**.

The same contradiction with [Beelzebub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub) in the same article:

*flavour one*

> In theological sources, predominantly Christian, Beelzebub is sometimes another name for the devil, similar to Satan. **He** is known in demonology as one of the seven princes of Hell.

*flavour two*

> The Septuagint renders the name as Baalzebub (βααλζεβούβ) and as Baal muian (βααλ μυιαν, "Baal of flies"). However, Symmachus may have reflected a tradition of **its** offensive ancient name, when he rendered it as Beelzeboul.

In some places it is referred like `he`, in others like `it`.

I can list many such inconsistencies but even that is enough to define the problem: I see no common rule and rationale behind this.

How should we use gender and personal pronouns with unnatural and unearthly creatures?

Comment: These 'individuals' are _personified_ - they are spoken about as though they were people, with a name and a gender.

Comment: Further to Kate's comment, I think there is a nuance here that depends on how near we feel the creature is to a human-like sentience in some way. Personally I would refer to Lucifer as 'he', a golem as 'it', and I'm really not sure about a minotaur!

Comment: Ships are often called *she* and they are sexless inanimate objects …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no strict rule.

If the monster has human characteristics, in particular, if it can speak, then it is more likely to be treated as a person with he/she pronouns. If it has identified gender, then he/she becomes more likely

In the particular examples you give, these seem to be breaking that rule for specific reasons: Scylla is being discussed as a daughter of Poseidon and so a goddess. She has an identified gender. On the other hand, if you are only considering the sea serpent, then "it" would be reasonable.

The description of Baphomet concerns a particular drawing, of a creature with indeterminate gender (A male goat head, but female breasts). In other contexts within that same article, the male deity is referred to as "he", but when talking about a picture, the use of "it" to refer to the picture is not incorrect.

As such, there should be no expectation of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Animals or creatures are *generally* referred as *'it'* pronoun. This practice has been there since years, but it is quite clear that when they are *personally attached* to humans, they take the pronouns *he or she* as per their gender **or** characters.

Long thing short, if the animals/creatures are referred *generally,* they are 'it.' If they are in the story or some possession, they are *s/he.*

Compare:

> **My dog,** whom I call Rocky, is my best friend. *He* comforts me when I play with *him*. 
>  Today, I saw **a stray dog**; *it* was shedding *its* hair.

When you see mixing up the pronouns, I'd guess that either it's a *writer's style* **or** something is referred *it* when unknown, but then *s/he* when it becomes a *character.*

Comment: here we speak not about pets which is highlighted in question, pets are the special case, and you example is very simplistic and does not cover all the scenarios

Comment: @Suncatcher you missed a big portion there - when it **becomes a character.**